# Process Landing Page to Update Salesforce Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpagesurl

Here is my use case : 
When a customers clicks on a CTA "call me now" (in an email), he lands on a landing page (created using marketing cloud - cloud pages).

On this landing page, thanks to ampscript, the field "callback_detail__c" in the data extension Task_Salesforce takes the value "immediate_callback".

Here is the ampscript used in the email that contains the CTA "call me now":

```
%%[
    var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @i
    var @subkey, @WhoId, @callback_detail__c 
    var @link

    set @numRowsToReturn = 0 
    set @subkey = _subscriberkey
    set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("ENT.Task_Salesforce", @numRowsToReturn, "WhoId, callback_detail__c ", "WhoId", @subkey) 
    set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
    set @link = 'http://cloud.mail.papernest.com/creneau_rappel'


]%%
```

Here is the ampscript used in the landing page :

```
%%[ var @subkey, @rows 
set @subkey = Requestparameter("_subscriberkey") 
set @rows = Lookup("ENT.Task_Salesforce", "WhoId", "WhoId", @subkey) ]%%

%%[var @result
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesForceObject ('Task', @subkey, 'callback_detail__c', 'immediate_callback')
]%%
```

But, when the lead lands on this landing page, nothing happens, the field callback_Detail__c does not take the value "immediate_callback".

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there shouldn’t be space between function name and parentheses:

```
%%[var @result
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesForceObject('Task', @subkey, 'callback_detail__c', 'immediate_callback')
]%%
```

Also keep in mind that *updateSingleSalesforceObject* does not update the data extension directly, but uses Marketing Cloud Connector to update the record directly on a Sales Cloud object. The way you phrase your question, it sounds to me you expect the data extension to be updated directly.

There is up to 15 minute latency between a record is updated in Sales Cloud and the corresponding synchronised data extension is updated. If you wait before checking the data extension, the value will eventually be updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lukas for your help ! Well, I have updated the function but, it is still not working...